# problem in adding tab bar in bottom of view in android

Tags: android, tabwidget

In my application I have a tab bar.  It contains four tabs in which I am showing a list view.  It was working fine, but now I need to shift the tab bar to the bottom of the screen.  When I changed my code to show tab bar at the bottom of the view, list views are showing in full screen overlapping the tab bar as well.

Here is the sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#000000">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/Label"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="Credit Balance"
                    android:background = "#55000000"
                    android:textColor = "#FF0033"
            />

            <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    **android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"**/>
            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
</FrameLayout>
```

I am adding 4 list views in 4 respective tabs with the following code

```
 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(NEW_TAB).setIndicator(NEW)
            .setContent(new Intent(this, NEWActivity.class)));
```

Please can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this

```
android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
```

line to your FrameLayout and with

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
```

in TabWidget

Comment: + 1 thank you... been trying to figure this one out for an hour